# How can I make a smooth expanding div from the bottom up to 85% of the viewport?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've this code here (Please open in expanded mode):

```css
#wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  background: gray;
  color: #fff;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#title {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

#notifications {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
      overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.entry {
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="title">Notifications</div>
  <div id="notifications">
    <div class="entry">Test</div>
    <div class="entry">Test</div>
    <div class="entry">Test</div>
    <div class="entry">Test</div>
    <div class="entry">Test</div>
    <div class="entry">Test</div>
    <div class="entry">Test</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It should be like in Google Maps when you explore the nearby. So like a slide up div from the bottom. The title should be visible when it's not expanded but not the notifications. When I click the title, I want to smoothly expand the element up to `85` percent of the viewport so that the user can scroll trough the notifications. When he clicks the title again, it should go back down to the initial state.

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change between two states, expanded and collapsed, you'll need some kind of JavaScript.

As far as the CSS, I'd suggest for `#wrapper` instead of using `bottom: 0`, using something like `top: calc(100% - 42px)` (the 42px should be whatever the height you want to be visible) for the collapsed state, and then `top: 15%` for the expanded state.

For the "smooth" part of it, you just need to add a transition animation.

Here's a basic codepen showing what I mean: https://codepen.io/milesgrover/pen/gOpbrpd